# Html2canvas returning blank white image when taking a screenshot

Tags: javascript, html, web, html2canvas

I have nested divs, but when I try to take a screenshot of the outermost div, it just returns a blank white screen with the size of the outer div.
This is the div that I have
I am trying to take the screenshot of tweetcorner div.
(PS) It works fine on mobile devices but on larger screens it just gives blank white image

```
<div id="tweetcorner">
<div id="infopanel">
    <div id="dp" class="dp">
    <div id="usernames">
        <div id="namefield">
            <p id="name">Name</p>
            <div id="valid">
                <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                    <path d="M22.5 12.5C22.5 10.92 21.625 9.55 20.352 8.9C20.506 8.465 20.59 7.995 20.59 7.5C20.59 5.29 18.88 3.502 16.772 3.502C16.302 3.502 15.852 3.586 15.436 3.752C14.818 2.415 13.51 1.5 12 1.5C10.49 1.5 9.18402 2.417 8.56302 3.75C8.14802 3.585 7.69702 3.5 7.22702 3.5C5.11702 3.5 3.40902 5.29 3.40902 7.5C3.40902 7.994 3.49202 8.464 3.64602 8.9C2.37402 9.55 1.49902 10.918 1.49902 12.5C1.49902 13.995 2.28102 15.298 3.44102 15.986C3.42102 16.156 3.40902 16.326 3.40902 16.5C3.40902 18.71 5.11702 20.5 7.22702 20.5C7.69702 20.5 8.14702 20.414 8.56202 20.25C9.18202 21.584 10.488 22.5 11.999 22.5C13.511 22.5 14.817 21.584 15.436 20.25C15.851 20.413 16.301 20.498 16.772 20.498C18.882 20.498 20.59 18.708 20.59 16.498C20.59 16.324 20.578 16.154 20.557 15.985C21.715 15.298 22.5 13.995 22.5 12.501V12.5ZM15.884 9.166L11.55 15.666C11.405 15.883 11.168 16 10.925 16C10.782 16 10.637 15.96 10.509 15.874L10.394 15.78L7.97902 13.365C7.68602 13.072 7.68602 12.597 7.97902 12.305C8.27202 12.013 8.74702 12.011 9.03902 12.305L10.809 14.072L14.634 8.332C14.864 7.987 15.33 7.896 15.674 8.125C16.02 8.355 16.114 8.821 15.884 9.165V9.166Z" fill="#1DA1F2"/>
                    </svg>
            </div>
        </div>
      
            
        <p id="atname"> @username</p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="tweetpanel">
    <p id="tweet">This is the sample tweet </p>
</div>

<div id="dateandtime">12 PM 4 July</div>
<div id="likes">

    <div class="likemenu">
        <div id="hearts">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M12 21.638H11.986C9.40295 21.59 1.94995 14.856 1.94995 8.478C1.94995 5.414 4.47495 2.724 7.35295 2.724C9.64295 2.724 11.183 4.304 11.999 5.454C12.813 4.306 14.353 2.724 16.644 2.724C19.524 2.724 22.048 5.414 22.048 8.479C22.048 14.855 14.594 21.589 12.011 21.636H12V21.638ZM7.35395 4.225C5.27395 4.225 3.45095 6.213 3.45095 8.48C3.45095 14.22 10.485 20.076 12.001 20.138C13.519 20.076 20.551 14.221 20.551 8.48C20.551 6.213 18.728 4.225 16.648 4.225C14.12 4.225 12.708 7.161 12.696 7.19C12.466 7.752 11.54 7.752 11.309 7.19C11.295 7.16 9.88395 4.225 7.35495 4.225H7.35395Z" fill="#b5b3b3"/>
                </svg>
            <p id="num1">12</p>
                
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="likemenu">
        <div id="hearts">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M14.0459 2.24199L9.89795 2.23199H9.89595C5.52195 2.23199 2.09595 5.65899 2.09595 10.034C2.09595 14.132 5.28195 17.24 9.56095 17.404V21.232C9.56095 21.34 9.60495 21.518 9.68095 21.635C9.82295 21.86 10.0649 21.982 10.3129 21.982C10.4509 21.982 10.5899 21.944 10.7149 21.864C10.9789 21.696 17.1879 17.724 18.8029 16.358C20.7049 14.748 21.8429 12.388 21.8459 10.046V10.029C21.8399 5.66199 18.4159 2.24199 14.0459 2.24099V2.24199ZM17.8329 15.214C16.6989 16.174 12.9709 18.619 11.0609 19.857V16.67C11.0609 16.256 10.7259 15.92 10.3109 15.92H9.91495C6.25495 15.92 3.59695 13.444 3.59695 10.034C3.59695 6.49999 6.36495 3.73199 9.89695 3.73199L14.0439 3.74199H14.0459C17.5779 3.74199 20.3459 6.50799 20.3479 10.038C20.3449 11.948 19.4059 13.882 17.8339 15.214H17.8329Z" fill="#b5b3b3"/>
                </svg>
                
            <p id="num2">34</p>
                
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="likemenu">
        <div id="hearts">
            <svg width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <path d="M17.53 7.46999L12.53 2.46999C12.237 2.17699 11.762 2.17699 11.47 2.46999L6.47001 7.46999C6.17601 7.76299 6.17601 8.23799 6.47001 8.52999C6.76401 8.82199 7.23701 8.82399 7.53001 8.52999L11.25 4.80999V15C11.25 15.414 11.586 15.75 12 15.75C12.414 15.75 12.75 15.414 12.75 15V4.80999L16.47 8.52999C16.616 8.67699 16.808 8.74999 17 8.74999C17.192 8.74999 17.384 8.67799 17.53 8.52999C17.823 8.23699 17.823 7.76299 17.53 7.46999V7.46999Z" fill="#b5b3b3"/>
                <path d="M19.708 21.944H4.292C3.028 21.944 2 20.916 2 19.652V14C2 13.586 2.336 13.25 2.75 13.25C3.164 13.25 3.5 13.586 3.5 14V19.652C3.5 20.089 3.855 20.444 4.292 20.444H19.708C20.145 20.444 20.5 20.089 20.5 19.652V14C20.5 13.586 20.836 13.25 21.25 13.25C21.664 13.25 22 13.586 22 14V19.652C22 20.916 20.972 21.944 19.708 21.944V21.944Z" fill="#b5b3b3"/>
                </svg>
                
            <p id="num">Share this Tweet</p>
                
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

The javascript file is

```
function takescreenshot(){


let div = document.getElementById("tweetcorner")
console.log(div.clientHeight)
console.log("sdsd")
html2canvas(div,{
    // width:1000,
    //  height:1000,

    allowTaint:true,
    useCORS:true
}).then(
    function (canvas) {
        
      //  console.log(canvas)


        saveAs(canvas.toDataURL(),'tweet.png')
    })
}
```

Comment: This might be normal, as you are using `svg`, the proper way is to convert your svg to a blob first, and then draw it in a canvas. From there it should works straight away without libraries. See https://levelup.gitconnected.com/draw-an-svg-to-canvas-and-download-it-as-image-in-javascript-f7f7713cf81f this looks like it